# Explaining output in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm a novice in Java programming and I'm trying to guess why the output of the following code:

```
public class ForLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        for (x=1; x<=2; x++) {
            x += 3;
        }
        System.out.print(x);
        }
}
```

is 5 and not 7! For the first iteration, 1 is added to 3 (result: 4) and it is stored in the variable x so x is 4. In the second iteration, we add 3 to 4 and we must obtain 7. The error might be easy to find but I can't catch it. Please help and thanks.

Comment: use a debugger, you will perfectly understand.

Comment: There is no second iteration...

Comment: hint: `x` the iteration variable is exactly the same as `x` the integer outside

Comment: run it in http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/#

Comment: Your x++ adds x += 1, 4 + 1 = 5. Conditional fails and method ends.

Answer (score 4):

This part:

```
    for (x=1; x<=2; x++)
```

means that x will be incremented at the end of each iteration. So, in the first iteration, 3 is added to x because of this:

```
    x += 3;
```

which results in a value of 4. Then, at the end of that iteration, x is incremented by 1, which comes to 5. Since 5 is greater than 2, the loop is then closed.

Comment: I got it. There's one more misunderstanding:
All the statements are executed then the update is performed?

Comment: Yes, after all statements within the for-loop structure (i.e. inside the curly braces) have been executed, the increment (x++) will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Big problem here using x as your iterator and your variable to update.  This is what the computer is evaulating.

When you are inside the for loop, x is initially 1, then you add three to it, and then your iterator on the for loop adds 1 to it afterwards (making it five).  At that point, your condition, (x<=2) is false for the for loop is complete.

change it to this and you will get your desired result:

```
public class ForLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        for (int y = 0; y <= 1; y++) {
            x += 3;
        }
        System.out.print(x);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In first pass the body is carried out, there x becomes 4. Then the incrementation is carried out. (The 3rd parameter of for loop) which results x to be 5.
In the second pass the condition is unmet as x is already 5 there but less than or equals to 2 is required to run the loop. So instead the loop will discontinue and x will be printed 5.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
int x;
for (x=1; x<=2; x++) {
    x += 3;
}
```

works as follows:

```
int x;
x = 1;           // for-initialization
while (x <= 2) { // for-condition
    x += 3;      // for-body
    x++          // for-increment
}
```

Particularly:

- the condition is tested before the loop body, and in your case
- the loop body has an effect on the condition.

Answer (score 0):

After the first iteration x is 4 as you say, but then x++ is executed, so x becomes 5. 5 is bigger than 2 (x<=2), so iteration stops.